# A bug in week of year in Java Calendar?

Tags: java, date, calendar

The following code calculates the workweek of a specific date.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(df.parse("2015-12-27 08:00:00"));
System.err.printf("%d.%02d\n", cal.getWeekYear(), cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

It currently prints 2016.01.

As I understand the work week number specification, 2016.01 is the first week having 4 days in 2016, but there is no way December 27 can belong to such week.

Is there a way to do it in Java 7 which will work for any year assuming weeks start on Monday?

Comment: Week rules are different around the world, what locale are you in ?

Comment: And what does `cal.getFirstDayOfWeek()` return for you, along with `cal.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()`?

Comment: @JonSkeet, it was set to 1, I should have set it to 4.

Comment: Tip: [`org.threeten.extra.YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html#of-int-int-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting Monday as first day of the week.

```
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

Comment: Also cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);